# how to download youtube video using pytube to cliant local drive not to server side

Tags: python, heroku, video, download, pytube

I created a youtube video downloader project using pytube in python django.

in `vies.py`

```
url = request.POST.get('url')
itag = request.POST.get('itag')

yt = YouTube(url)
yt.streams.get_by_itag(itag).download()

messages.success(request, 'Download successful')
return redirect('/')
```

everything work good but when i run this code, video were download but it is download to the project directory.
if i hard code the download directory its work fine on local host
but when i deploy django to heroku server its does not download on cliant local storage

my question is, how can i download thie pytube video to cliant side storage not on server side?
is there anty way to grab the users download directory?

if i do like this still not download to users local storage while my code on heroku live server
its work fine on localhost.

```
url = request.POST.get('url')
itag = request.POST.get('itag')

path = pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path.home())
dirs = os.path.join(path, 'Downloads')

yt = YouTube(url)
yt.streams.get_by_itag(itag).download(dirs)

messages.success(request, 'Download successful'+str(dirs))
return redirect('/')
```

and one thing that user could be moble user or desktop user

project link on heroku
https://metube-dl.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This code will always download to the server. "its work fine on localhost"—that's because when you run the application locally your local machine _is_ the server. You cannot access the client's filesystem, and that is a very very good thing. Consider the security implications if a website could read private files in your documents folder or save malware to your hard drive!

Comment: Well, I understand but how could I download to selected directory . Is there any way to do that.

Comment: No. Even using JavaScript you don't have access to the user's filesystem. The best you can do is to send the user a file to be downloaded in their browser, which might go to a default location or might prompt them for a location.

Comment: That's as much help as I'm willing to give about this question, though. I'm not interested in helping you build a tool to pirate content from YouTube.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how could they do.      https://en.savefrom.net/197/